# how to set auto-reconnect=True when connecting with autobahn.twisted.component

Tags: python, websocket, twisted, autobahn

When trying to connect a python app to a Crossbar router using the recommended component-decorator approach, how and where would i pass the `auto_reconnect=True` value to the transport. I can set the parameters in `Component.transports`, but that alone doesn't 'activate' auto-reconnect.

When using the inheriting approach with `ApplicationRunner`, you can set that when calling `run(app, auto_reconnect=True)`.

The docs only mention how to set the "strategy":
http://autobahn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/autobahn.twisted.html#autobahn.twisted.component.Component

Also, when setting `max_retries` to -1, it doesn't connect at all ("No remaining transports to try"), instead of infinitely trying to reconnect.

Here's how I'm testing:

```
from autobahn.twisted.component import Component, run
from autobahn.twisted.util import sleep
from autobahn.wamp.types import RegisterOptions
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks, returnValue

class App:

    component = Component(
        transports=[
            {
                'type': 'websocket',
                'url': 'ws://<router-IP>:8080/ws',
                'max_retries': 10,
                # 'max_retries': -1,
                'initial_retry_delay': 3,
                'max_retry_delay': 120,
                'retry_delay_growth': 1,
                'retry_delay_jitter': 0.1,
                'options': {
                    'open_handshake_timeout': 0,
                    'close_handshake_timeout': 0,
                    'auto_ping_interval': 0,
                    'auto_ping_timeout': 0,
                    'auto_reconnect': True
                }
            }
        ],
        realm='test_realm'
    )

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def start(cls):
        # do startup stuff, then
        run([cls.component])

    @staticmethod
    @component.on_join
    @inlineCallbacks
    def join(session, details):

        print("joined {}: {}".format(session, details))
        yield sleep(1)
        print("Calling 'com.example'")
        res = yield session.call(u"example.foo", 42, something="nothing")
        print("Result: {}".format(res))
        yield session.leave()

    @component.register(
        u"example.foo",
        options=RegisterOptions(details_arg='details'),
    )
    @inlineCallbacks
    def foo(*args, **kw):
        print("foo called: {}, {}".format(args, kw))
        for x in range(10, 0, -1):
            print("  returning in {}".format(x))
            yield sleep(5)
        print("returning '42'")
        returnValue(42)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = App()
    app.start()
```

EDIT:
The reason for me to use Component is, that you can't set websocket options with ApplicationRunner.
https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/issues/838

In an environment with unstable network conditions, the settings shall be quite tolerant. Also, a reconnect should be done anytime the connection was closed.
Maybe my approach here is in the wrong direction at all, i would appreciate any advice.

Comment: The linked docs don't talk about most of the items you're setting in the dict you're passing as a transport.  What gave you the idea you could set things like `max_retries` there?

Comment: @Jean-Paul i traced it down in the sources. The items defined in transport get passed to `autobahn.wamp.component._Transport`.